# Highlight negation operator in an IDE

Tags: java, ide, syntax-highlighting

I prefer Eclipse, but I'd love to know if there is any IDE anywhere that can detect, and offers syntax highlighting for, the negation operator (!). It's a critical thing, but it's often lost between long method names and an open parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Techrocket9's comments in @dkatzel's answer, I eventually found my way to wiki articles on how to [create an editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_an_editor_for_my_own_language%3F) and providing coloring for [custom syntax rules](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_syntax_coloring_in_an_editor%3F). These two articles have enough related information that I can begin trying my hand at creating a plugin. If anyone has experience in this, feel free to add to this community wiki answer. Otherwise, I'll update this when I have something.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the Preferences->Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring dialog, you can change the font and colors for operators which include ! to be whatever color, bold, italic, strikethrough, underline you want.  I'm not sure if you can just do ! though.

Comment: Eclipse is open source; if the option isn't already there Jonas could conceivably add it. It would probably be less work than learning a new IDE.

Comment: That's probably true. I'd definitely learn some interesting stuff that way, too. While I could highlight all operators, I don't want all my == in bright bold red. But that's just my preference; it might be a potential solution for others. 

@Techrocket9, can you point me to a recommended resource? I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: @jonas.ninja You can get the source code at http://git.eclipse.org/c/

Can't help you with building it though.